# In constraint Query Slow?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which taking time .Below is that query-

```
SELECT
    m1.mes_id,
    m1.body, 
    m1.subject,
    m1.frm_id AS mem_id,
    m1.date 
FROM 
    messages_system_new m1 
WHERE 
    m1.mes_id IN 
        (SELECT
            MAX(mn1.mes_id) AS mes_id 
        FROM messages_system_new mn1
        WHERE
            mn1.mem_id = '401' 
            AND mn1.frm_id != '401' 
            AND mn1.trashed_user NOT LIKE '%401%' 
            AND mn1.type = 'message' 
            AND mn1.folder = 'inbox' AND mn1.is_spam='N' 
        GROUP BY mn1.frm_id
        )
```

when fired EXPLAIN its giving

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY m1  ALL (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  6091    Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  mn1 ref mem_id,frm_id   mem_id  8   const   59  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

What does it mean and how can I improve the query?

Comment: can you lease post the schema of the table involved

Comment: make sure that you have created a index for field `mes_id` in table `messages_system_new`

Comment: @Lake yeah! its primary key (mes_id)

Comment: add an index for frm_id it will speed up group by.

Comment: @Ghigo mem_id,frm_id and trashed_user are already indexed.

Comment: If you don't post table structure we can only guess it and it's a time waste.

Comment: Index on trashed user is pretty useless for this query. The leading wildcard will prevent it from being useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly try it using a JOIN instead. Something like this

```
SELECT
    m1.mes_id,
    m1.body, 
    m1.subject,
    m1.frm_id AS mem_id,
    m1.date 
FROM messages_system_new m1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT mn1.frm_id  MAX(mn1.mes_id) AS mes_id 
        FROM messages_system_new mn1
        WHERE
            mn1.mem_id = '401' 
            AND mn1.frm_id != '401' 
            AND mn1.trashed_user NOT LIKE '%401%' 
            AND mn1.type = 'message' 
            AND mn1.folder = 'inbox' AND mn1.is_spam='N' 
        GROUP BY mn1.frm_id
        ) Sub1
ON m1.mes_id = Sub1.mes_id
```

What are the indexes on messafes_system_new?

Comment: thank u so much... BTW!! mem_id,frm_id and trashed_user are already indexed.

Comment: For this query the index on trashed_user is not useful (might well be for other queries) due to the leading wildcard. However if this is a common query then it might be worth adding an index on the columns mem_id, frm_id, type and folder. Note that mysql will only use one index on a table in a query, hence if you have an index on mem_id and another on frm_id, only one of those will be used (hence using indexes on multiple columns when necessary)